# Setting a folder for my views on a maven project in Eclipse instead of WebContent

Tags: eclipse, maven, view

I am currently creating a mvn project with tomcat.

The main issue is that after I am done coding my project in Eclipse it doesnt appear on the list of projects available to run in my Tomcat (8.5.61) server and what i found on the internet is that i needed to convert my project to be a faceted form and enable the Dynamic Web Module  option which select a folder from where to pick my resources and i want to be able to do that but just from my code and not from the IDE.

This is line of code that i am using to select the rute of my views folder:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("Web")
public class SpringWeb  implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

So I am asking to know a way to bypass the process of making it faceted , which seems to cause Eclipse to overwrite anyother rute i try to set.

Comment: How exactly does Deployment Assembly affect this?

Comment: For what i had seen it is there where i can tell eclipse from which folder get its resources, and i want to do that but in the code not in the ide configuration.